# arrange messages by UID

Tags: c#, arraylist, linda

i use this code for read mails.

```
 Lazy<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(mailcondition, headersOnly);
```

Each message has a property called Value, and each value has its own properties, including UID.

Now I'm going to arrange the messages based on the UID.

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following.

```
messages.OrderBy(x=>x.Value.Value.UID)
```

Since messages are `Lazy<MailMessage>`, `messages[x].Value` would give you a **MailMessage instance**. Hence to access UID, you need to use `messages[x].Value.Value.UID`.

Comment: Are you still using Lazy<MailMessage>[] or are using IEnumerable<MailMessage> ? If you are using Lazy<T>, "x=>x.Value" would give you an instance of MailMessage and not MailMessage.Value